# python how to correctly make a subprocess call doing with os.system

Tags: python, shell

Can't get it right after reading some examples:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal sh python gateway.py 1 "+ str(line.split(' ')[2]))
```

how to write it to subprocess ? the terminal is saying the above is deprecated

```
subprocess.check_output("python","gateway.py 1 "+str(line.split(' ')[2]))
```

tried this one above but it does not work.

Comment: You really should not need `gnome-terminal sh` at the start of the command. You're even invoking it from a Python script, so you could import gateway.py and call the relevant method directly.

Comment: @i0b0 , well that wouldn't help me fix what i'm needing ... because i'm doing a process that waits the a port message thus that's why i'm needing to open other process in other terminals.

Comment: I don't understand that sentence, but I'm having a very hard time understanding why `gnome-terminal` or `sh` would help with waiting for anything.

Comment: @i0b0 [edit] the gnome-terminal opens another terminal, i can't just import gateway.py ,because that wouldn't solve my problemn since i'm already at gateway.py i need to open others gateways , (that are running in other setup if/else), and i need to open these gateways in other terminals because those processes are python socket operators that are listening too a port, thus if u do it on a single terminal/thread it will keep waiting and won't allow the other ones to wait too.

Comment: Nothing about this needs a terminal or a shell - all you need to do is to run multiple processes. You can use [Python multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) for that.

Comment: I'll try to understand it them, thnks

Comment: PS: [The difference between terminal, shell, etc.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4132/3645)

Answer (score 1):

You still need `gnome-terminal` and `sh`; that doesn't really change going from `system` to `check_output`. The *single* argument should be a list containing the pre-split command line you used with `os.system`.

```
subprocess.check_output(["gnome-terminal",
                         "sh",
                         "python",
                         "gateway.py",
                         "1",
                         line.split(' ')[2]
                        ])
```

Comment: Then you can drop `gnome-terminal` (and probably `sh`; it doesn't seem to serve any purpose either way).